# Development database doesn't reset (not null)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

In seeds.rb I have a single record for my Messages model:

```
Message.create!(email: "example@example.com",
               name:  "Example User",
               content: "This is my message")
```

If I run `rake db:seed` I get the error message:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Username has already been taken
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
...
```

If I run `bundle exec rake db:reset` I get the error:

```
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0734s
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: messages.name: INSERT INTO "messages" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
...
```

Email in the Message model is indeed required. But still when I reset the db, I don't see how this record could be invalid. And email does not need to be unique, so why does the seed command give such an error?

The model file for messages:

```
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :content
  validates :name,      presence: true,
                        length: { maximum: 255 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email,     presence: true,
                        length: { maximum: 255 },
                        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :content,   presence: true,
                        length: { maximum: 600 }
```

Messages migration file:

```
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :name,       null: false,    limit: 255
      t.string :email,      null: false,    limit: 255
      t.string :content,    null: false,    limit: 600

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure what is causing this problem...

**Update:** I'm lost, I now also get an error message when seeding even without the Message.create! lines in the seeds file. The error says `rake aborted! ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Username has already been taken`. But how can this be since I first run `bundle exec rake db:reset`? Doesn't this remove all the data from the db and wouldn't this by definition mean they can't already be taken?

My seeds file is:

```
User.create!(fullname:  "Example User",
                    username: "fakename0",
                    email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                    admin: true,
                    activated: true,
                    activated_at: Time.zone.now,
                    password:              "foobar",
                    password_confirmation: "foobar")

User.create!(fullname:  "Example User 2",
                    username: "fawwkename0",
                    email: "exaaample@railstutorial.org",
                    admin: false,
                    activated: true,
                    activated_at: Time.zone.now,
                    organization: "organization",
                    password:              "foobar",
                    password_confirmation: "foobar")

99.times do |n|
  username  = "fakename#{n+1}"
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(username:               username,
               email:                  email,
               password:               password,
               password_confirmation:  password,
               activated: true,
               activated_at: Time.zone.now)
```

**Update 2:** I found out that running `rake db:reset` already seeds the db (or at least the db wasn't empty after this command). Still this doesn't explain why I can't seed it with

```
Message.create!(email: "example@example.com",
                name:  "Example User",
                content: "This is my message")
```

Seeding this data generates the error: `rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: messages.name: INSERT INTO "messages" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?) /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in 'step' ...`

Comment: By the way, if I remove the record from the seeds file, everything runs smooth and the reset and seeds commands don't produce any errors.

Comment: Just a tip. Don't validate email address, using regexp (by format style). Simple checking for `@` enough.

Comment: I found out that `rake db:reset` already seeds the db, which partly caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `attr_accessor :name, :email, :content` from the model file solved it. Don't really know why. I added this line because it is included in the tutorial: http://matharvard.ca/posts/2014/jan/11/contact-form-in-rails-4/ But also without that line the messages form still seems to be working.